# ssl page with ssl iframe broken on android 5.1

Tags: android, ssl, iframe

I have an ssl page with an iframe that is another ssl page. This works fine on my desktop using chrome or edge.

But on Mobile, using android 5.1 and either Chrome or FF the iframe is not displayed, there is no error, just a blank area with a little page icon with a frowney face.

There is no mixed content as far as I can tell.

On the same site I also have youtube videos that run in an iframe and they work fine.

Page with iframe that doesn't work with Adroid:
https://prolabprints.com/order-online/simple-file-uploader/

the page that is in the iframe:
https://uploads.prolabprints.com/

The main site is a static site hosted via AWS S3 and then Cloudfront, using their free TLS cert.

The iframe page (uploader) is running on an EC2 instance, and uses a free letsencrypt cert.

Here is a page that has an iframe for a youtube video that works when the uploads page is broken on android:
https://prolabprints.com/videos/roes-intro-video/

I have tried an Ipod touch, and it works. I have tried with a couple android phones and they don't work.

I have also tried removing `onload="scroll(0,0)"` from the iframe and it doesn't make a difference.

I have tried doing the url for the iframe as //uploads.prolabprints.com like the youtube embed is and that doesn't work.

Why would the iframe for my uploader not work when the Youtube iframe does? Is this because of the type of ssl cert that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short look at [the SSLabs report for uploads.prolabprints.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=uploads.prolabprints.com) shows that the server sends an incomplete certificate chain:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.
>   ...
>   Chain issues  Incomplete, Extra certs

While desktop browsers often deal with this kind of problem by downloading the missing intermediate certificates from the internet (Google Chrome) or using cached certificates from visits to other sites (Firefox) mobile browsers are usually not that much forgiving.

A closer look reveals that there was an attempt to send an intermediate certificate but that instead of "Let's Encrypt Authority X3" the certificate for "Let's Encrypt Authority X1" was sent, causing "Incomplete" (X3 missing) and "Extra certs" (X1 not needed).

Comment: Thank You  - I had done that report when the cert was issued, and earlier today on the main page but didn't do the uploads page today. Apparently the renewal of the lets encrypt cert just happened on my server in the last few days and caused an issue. I used the ACME client, and others are having the same issue, should have looked over there first. https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple/issues/177

Comment: more: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/iis-8-5-building-incorrect-chain-with-lets-encrypt-authority-x3/13320/24  looks like LE changed the Authority from X1 to X3 but is still using the same key, and IIS seems to choose the wrong one. I am on Win 2012 R2 IIS 8.5. Doesn't seem to be any solution, removing all the certs and reinstalling doesn't seem to work as IIS is somehow keeping a copy hidden somewhere.

Comment: I was unable to get past this, it was an AWS EC2 instance so I just launched another one and used it instead. With a fresh install of Win 2012 I was able to setup all the certificates and it all works as expected, back to an A grade on SSLabs.